# Is it "dangerous" to rely on a framework, such as Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, compatibility

I was wondering whether it might be dangerous to rely on frameworks such as Bootstrap too much? I always used to create the most things myself so I can be very sure that it will be supported in later versions of my projects. But by now I rely heavily on Bootstrap or, in other words, if Bootstrap was shut down tomorrow, my page would not work at all. So this is a question for all the professionals out there: Do you rely on such services or what do you do to make sure that your pages will still work.

(Question#2: Solution would be to download the Bootstrap files and include them in your projects. Is that already the answer to my question?)

Comment: You seem to be confusing frameworks and CDNs

Answer (score 0):

We can say it about every platform or framework that we use. It's unlikely that Bootstrap will shutdown and drop suddenly the support, at least not for near future as it seems to me.

It's more complicated when you use a content managment system for example which has database that store your data or in case of third-party services which your data stored on their servers and in their control.

For Bootstrap you shouldn't worry much as there is a large community around it and even if one day, let's say, the project will be discontinued so you still store your JS and CSS files of the framework on your server (in case you didn't used thier CDN option). Your website will continue to work and you always have the option to move to another framework as you wish. Althought, for now, it's unlikely to happen.